# how to make HELM stop when TRAMP asks me for my password?

Tags: helm, tramp

I have this problem:

[image]

Is this a bug? Is this something I can avoid now while a patch comes to Helm?

Comment: It's not a bug. When you work through TRAMP with Helm and when a password is required, `helm-find-files` asks for your password and after you enter the password, you can resume your file browsing session normally without having to exit and invoke Helm again.

Comment: So... it is not a bug that Helm displays my password?

Comment: Really? I thought that you wanted to create a file on a remote server and was asked for a password. I think the cursor is accidentally moved to the Helm buffer. If your cursor remains in the minibuffer, entering password should not appear in the Helm buffer. Could you try it again?

Comment: Could you execute `(setq helm-prevent-escaping-from-minibuffer t)` and  try again?

Comment: Ha! Well, my cursor  was on the minibuffer all the time, I was able to see my password as I was typing it!

Comment: Did you execute the above code to not letting cursor accidentally escape the minibuffer? If so, then file a bug report and steps to reproduce at [helm](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm). I also use Tramp with `helm-find-files` but never encounter such situation.

Comment: Ok I've tried and could not reproduce it even when cursor escaped minibuffer. Could you show me your Helm configuration?

Comment: Yup, same results... my org conf is [here](https://github.com/shackra/.emacs.d/blob/master/emacs-init.org#terminado-org-mode)

Comment: Let's try to reproduce it at bare minimum Helm. In your Helm installed directory in `~/.emacs.d/elpa`, there's a script called `emacs-helm.sh`. It starts bare minimum Emacs with Helm for testing bugs. If it is reproducible in that environment, then it is a bug in Helm. Could you try that while I check your configuration?

Comment: I cloned and tested your configuration. For some reason, I could not perform `ssh` inside `helm-find-files`. It got stuck after I finished entering `ssh:test@localhost:`. After trials and errors for a while, I found out that `global-relative-buffers-mode` is the culprit. Could you disable it and try again? On a side note, you could remove these helm variables: `helm-quick-update` for [this reason](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/pull/114) and the delay variables since those are the default values now.

Comment: The issue remains! http://i.imgur.com/XfhuKvw.png

Comment: Are you entering password for a GPG file?

Comment: err... No! I just randomly type that. No matter what I type, the password is shown in Helm.

Comment: How do you get to the password prompt? With `ssh:name@host"? Anyway, if this is reproducible in `~/emacs-helm.sh`, you should report the issue to Helm maintainer, with a reproducible steps and your Emacs version.

Comment: I'm actually trying to access a FTP server. And thanks for the advice!

Comment: Fyi, I submited [a bug report](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/issues/718).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was fixed in the commit [9f64244](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/commit/9f64244881c24e31bb2efc7da5b63703ae620220). You could try again without any error now. The error is not related to the interaction between Tramp and Helm but AngeFTP and Helm.